# Connecting with python-ldap to ldaps - An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: python, ssl, ldap

the script

```
import ldap
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW)

try:
    l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://ldapHost:ldapPort')
    ldap_base = "ou=XXX,o=XXX"
    query = "(cn=XXXXX)"
    result = l.search_s(ldap_base, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, query)
except ldap.LDAPError, e:
    print e
```

returns with the following error:

```
{'info': u'An unexpected TLS packet was received.', 'errno': 2, 'desc': u"Can't contact LDAP server"}
```

Is there any other option I need to specify? Or using cert files is mandatory in this case? I can connect to the ldap server without specifying any cert files.

versions:

- Python 2.7.13
- python-ldap 3.1.0

Thanks!